# How to get YouTube "watch later" feed?

Tags: youtube-api

At last, there comes the api

[watch later api](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/support-for-watch-later-list.html)

How can I get YouTube watch later feed?  I cannot find the feed type in http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds.html

Is there any other way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Watch later is a [user feed](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles.html). This particular feed's URL is https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<user>/watch_later?v=2.

Comment: Could it be that it does not work anymore? Or do I need to turn this feature somehow on in YouTube’s profile settings?

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles), there's a `<link>` element in a profile request:

```
<gd:feedLink rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.watchlater' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/watch_later?v=2' countHint='15'/>
```

So, if you're using PHP, here's how to get a specific `<link>` element:

```
$link = $feed->getLink('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.watchlater');
if($link!==null) {
    var_dump($link);
}
```